# get data with chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

How can I get data from

```js
 chrome.storage.sync.get
```

and store his value on a variable?
I have been creating a **CRUD** within chrome extension but when trying to **R**etrieve the data, it looks like `chrome.storage.sync.get` don't return data.

```js
const STORAGE = chrome.storage.sync;

function getURLs() {
  let urls = [];
  STORAGE.get(["urls"], result => {
    urls = result.urls || [];
  });
  return urls;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: thanks for formating [@Raghul SK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9856853/raghul-sk)

Comment: [@hindmost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost) This answer is useful but still can't found the right one. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: [hindmost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost) Already found the answer, many thanks for being kind of code hero!!